# How to return the elements of an array from my database into my php as Ajax links

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, database

Basically I have a database and I'm making a webpage with PHP.
I get a row of Elements from my database and put them into an array.
I need to display this array in my webpage, and the elements out of it have to be ajax links that display more information.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";
    $categories1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($categories1)) {
    $id = $row["name"];
    $echo "$id";
```

This is my array where i have a list of names and i print it there, i want my prints to be links.
Any help? I'm pretty desperate

Comment: print as a json object and read that object after getting response in AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Make the datatype of AJAX call as JSON in the javascript and return a json encoded string from php. Then in the success block of the AJAX call , parse it by JSON.parse()

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";
$categories1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($categories1)) {
   $categoryDetails[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode( $categoryDetails );
```

Comment: Can you add some description to your code. [Code only answers are discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)

Comment: Ohh sorry I forgot

Comment: Hey, could we maybe open a chat so I can ask you a few questions? I'm new to PHP